# how to change function promise typescript into es6?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

i have this code

```
  function isSuccess<ValueTypes>(
    response: PromiseSettledResult<ValueTypes[]>
  ): response is PromiseFulfilledResult<ValueTypes[]> {
    return 'value' in response;
  }
```

how can I successfully convert this into es6 format?

this code is where I will apply it

```
const result = (await Promise.allSettled(searchRequestBuilder))
    .filter(isSuccess)
    .filter((response) => response.value)
    .map(({ value }) => {
      let list: MetaDataTypes = {
        value_id: '',
      };
      if (value[0]) {
        list = value[0];
      }
      return list;
    });
```

Comment: Just [compile the typescript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/AQMwrgdgxgLglgewsOBnAymKUCmrUA8AagIYA2YOAKgJ4AOeAfABQCwAUMF8AE551JUOAFzAACjwQBbNDnQ4YMMjgAmAJTxgyMYuUq0GqANoBdRhy4BKUX1QCIQlKnGSZQgGJaQcMsvWbtXQpqejxTRmAAbwtuPhgwHmQAcgA3PRwklGRbeyEAbhiAXyA) to javascript?!

Comment: yes, in arrow function

Comment: Notice that `function` syntax is totally normal ES6. No need to convert that into an arrow function.

Comment: its just for consistency since it looks bad if theres in a function format instead of const

Comment: @user16691768 just remove the first filter you are checking the truthiness of `response.value` which will be true only when the response has value

Comment: If I remove `.filter(isSuccess)`, the error will be `Property 'value' does not exist on type 'PromiseSettledResult<Lead411DataTypes>'.
  Property 'value' does not exist on type 'PromiseRejectedResult'.` in response.`value` @RameshReddy

Comment: @RameshReddy The OP is converting from TypeScript to ES6; there are no types.

Comment: The answer is to remove all of the TypeScript-specific syntax. Anywhere you see `:` or `<type>`. But honestly, paste your code into [the TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play) and look at the right pane, making sure the JS pane is selected.

Comment: Do you basically just need to convert `function` into `() =>`?

Comment: @RameshReddy `PromiseSettledResult` is a builtin type, and no you should not add a `value` property to it. But I don't see how this is relevant at all, OP doesn't want to use TypeScript.

Comment: @Bergi I misunderstood the question. If he wants to use types then I guess he has to add value to the generic type `Lead411DataTypes` he's passing and remove all types if he wants to use js

Comment: I just only need to declare Typescript functions via Lambda expression format. Should be const isSuccess <MetaDataTypes> = () => {} to avoid using the declarative word function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is:

```
 const isSuccess = (
    response: PromiseSettledResult<Lead411DataTypes>
  ): response is PromiseFulfilledResult<Lead411DataTypes> => {
    return 'value' in response;
  };
```